# How do I move an element inside an iframe by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to copy some elements to an iframe. My code is this:

```
<div id="some">
  <div id="more">Something</div>
  <input id="inp>
</div>
<iframe id="myframe"></iframe>
```

I am doing this in Javascript to move all elements from *some* div to the iframe:

```
var allElements = $('div').children();
for(i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++)
{
   $(allElements[i]).detach().appendTo($('#myframe'));
}
```

However, it's not working because iframe has its own html and body. So, how can I get to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `.contents().find("body")`, you will be able to modify the dom.  So:

```
var allElements = $('div').children();
for(i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++)
{
   $(allElements[i]).detach().appendTo($('#myframe').contents().find("body"));
}
```

So, check out the jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/251u04cq/